# Callbacks in ASP.NET Core Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core

I have two `asp.net core` webservices, one is in my local network and does not have a public reachable IP and the other is accessable from the internet.

Users talk to the public service, which should inform the local service to do some stuff.

Is there a way to register my local webservice and send a callback?
Do you have any other ideas how to solve that.

Comment: Could you just use HttpClient inside the public webservice to call your local webservice?

Comment: But i do not have an address to call the local webservice, and I would need this for the HttpClient

Comment: Why you don't have an address? Maybe you can clarify your arcitecture a bit.

Comment: I can't reach my local webservice from my external webservice, because the local webservice is in my local network and has no public ip address assigned.

Comment: So machines that host these two services do not share any common network?

Comment: From my local service I can access the public service via internet. But the other way round there is no direct connection available. That is why  I want to register my local service to the public service and send a callback as soon something happens.